# Declare an array fib[22]. If the user asks for the 22nd or greater Fibonacci number, output an error msg

Tags: c, arrays, error-handling, fibonacci

I need to declare an array fib[22] in C language and if the user inputs a number greater than 22 i need to output an error msg. Can someone please help me wkith this?

So far my code just outputs results of fibonacci numbers. Can someone please help me further?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    int n ;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i;
    if (n <= 1)
        printf("%d\n", n);
    else {
        int f[n + 1];
        f[0] = 0;
        f[1] = 1;

        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            *(f + i) = *(f + i - 1) + *(f + i - 2);
        }
        printf("%d\n", f[n]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code so that we can answer more precisely. We don't know how you are reading the input. But in general: `if (input > 22) { /* error msg */ }`. That's a bit obvious so probably you have more that you need help with. But we can't help unless you ask a clear question. Best if you can provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you have tried so far.

Comment: @kaylum sorry about that, i just included the code. Can you please take a look? How do i show an error is the input exceeds 22?

Comment: I don't understand what your difficulty is. Isn't what you want just: `if (n > 22) { fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n"); return 1; }`

Comment: Do you know how to program computers?

Answer (score 1):

for best practice you should check the input prior to performing any processes. This ensures the program stops running prior to printing any numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2){
        printf(stderr, "usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }
    //store the 2nd argument in variable for value comparison.
    int n ;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n > 22) {
        printf(stderr, "number must be less then 22\n");
        return(1);
    }


    int i;
    if (n <= 1)
        printf("%d\n", n);
    else {
        int f[n + 1];
        f[0] = 0;
        f[1] = 1;

        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++){
            *(f + i) = *(f + i - 1) + *(f + i - 2);
        }
        printf("%d\n", f[n]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood you right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fib[22], i, n;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n <= 0 || n > 22)
    {

        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < 22; i++)
    {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    }

    printf("The fib number is: %d\n", fib[n - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```